# cake php accessing a table

Tags: php, cakephp

I just started cakephp following there tutorials
I'm able to grab the posts table in my post controller and spew it onto my index.ctp

In my view for the post controller i also want to list the User name that posted the article. My post table has a user_id, so i need to match it to my user table and pass it along

```
class PostsController extends AppController {

public function index() {
      //passes values to the view
      $this->set('posts', $this->Post->find('all')); 
      //is "Post" a post method? or is it the name of the table? i'm unsure of the syntax

      $this->set('users', $this->Users->find('all')); //this does not work

    }
}
```

thank you for your help with this basic question

Comment: try $this->Post->User->find('all');

Comment: did you set up post and user association ?

Comment: no i dont think so :(

Comment: Associations are the very basics of CakePHP, I'd suggest to take a look at the Cookbook: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you have already set a belongsTo association (Post belongsTo User) and/or a hasMany association (User hasMany Post). If so, cake will automaticly brings the associated models (unless you put $recursive = -1 on your model).
Thus you'll have access to the users related to each post on the view:    posts[i]['User']
You can also use this on your view to see the view variables:

```
debug($this->viewVars)
```

put this on your Post model if you don't:

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'User' => array(
        'className'  => 'User',
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
    )
);
```

Comment: I tried debug($this->viewVars) in my view for the post controller and i dont get any user variables. So I dont think I did what you mention. I'm just trying to grab the user table so i can do a for loop in my view to find and match. Is this not the right way?

Comment: No it's not the right way. I think you didn't associate the models.
put this on your post model:
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'User' => array(
            'className'  => 'User',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        )
    );

Comment: i'm not sure what associate the models mean. I'm following the cakephp tutorial, all the posts have a column user_id that returns a # and all my users in the user table have a unique id that matches up. What do i need to do to my post model? I thought the post model only gets used when I add a file? How is it related when i'm only reading?

Comment: I've just edited my post to show you how to set up an association

Comment: thank you! that did it, can you break it down for me what that means 
//why didn't you use $hasOne instead of $belongsTo, cause each article can only have one author right?
public $belongsTo = array(
    'User' => array( //so this is the table
        'className'  => 'User', //what is this for?
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id', //it will match to this?
    )
);

Comment: yes cause each article has only on author.
By the way each user has many post so you should set a hasMany association on your User model to, so you can access users using the posts.

Answer (score 1):

You must use ['recursive'](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#find)

```
$this->Post->find('all', array(
    'recursive' => 2,
    // ...
));
```

Of course, you first need to [link models together](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html)

Comment: can you explain what 'recursive' => 2 means?

Comment: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#recursive. In short: recursive = -1 return all Post data, recursive = 0 return all Posts and all domain data (Users), recursive = 2 return its domain and its associated data and so on... If you don't know what right number is just try any (until you learn this) :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you load models corretly (in case you want to load the User model inside PostsController).
So simply add this attribute inside your class controller.

```
public $uses = array('Post','User');
```

to link models together . u need to add the association inside your Post model .

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'User'=>array(
        'className'=> 'User',
        'foreignKey'=>'user_id'
        )
);
```

and i you want to retrieve data from database you have to set your recursivity and there is two ways 
first one :

```
$posts = $this->Post->find('all',array('recursive'=>2));
// or
$this->Post->recursive = 2;
$posts = $this->Post->find('all');
```

second one : use the Containable behavior 
set the recursivity to -1 in the AppModel and include the behavior

```
public $recursive = -1;
public $actsAs = array('Containable');
```

so simply u can retieve posts with any other linked models like that

```
$posts = $this->Post->find('all',array(
     'contain'=>array('User'),
      // ...
)));
```